# Vagrant - The host path of the shared folder is missing: ../keys

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine

When I try to run `vagrant up` or `vagrant provision` I get this error:

There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

vm:

```
* The host path of the shared folder is missing: ../../../../keys
```

I already tried `vagrant destroy` but I get the same error.

Does anybody have suggestions on what to check?

I'm on ubuntu 15.10

Answer (score 2):

I've had this once before and there's plenty of possible solutions on the web.

What worked for me is to simply create the folder that's apparently missing. Do the following (easiest on command line):

```
cd /path/to/wherever/it/is/supposed/to/be/
mkdir keys
```

You should then be able to `vagrant up` fine.